# Pas d'accent circonflexe à la troisième personne du singulier pour « se taire »

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison

Cette citation provient de la page 115 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> *Plaire* (*à*) (to be pleasing), *déplaire* (*à*) (to displease) and *se taire* (to be quiet) are conjugated like *connaître* except that there is only one *s* in the plural forms. There is no circumflex on the *i* in the third person singular of *se taire*.

On “plaît” ou on ”déplaît”, mais on “se tait”.

Y aurait-il une différence de prononciation entre “se tait” et “<s>se taît</s>” (en supposant que cette forme existe) ou “se (dé)plaît” ? Pourquoi ou pourquoi pas ?
D'où vient cette exception pour **se taire** ?  Je cherche une raison possible à cette exception.

Comment: http://www.orthographe-recommandee.info/regles4.htm

Comment: Autre remarque (tant qu'on y est), "méditer" a une connotation spirituelle ("méditation religieuse", "méditer sur le sens de la vie", etc.). "Réfléchir" serait plus approprié pour cette remarque.

Comment: @Lamine: Je vous suis reconnaissant.

Answer (score 2):

Both "plaît" and "tait" sound equal.

But "plaire" comes from "plaisir".

We can see there was a "il plaist" form in the past: http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/plaire

Therefore, some vowels + "s" are reduced to a "î" or "ô" in modern form, like "hospital" => "hôpital", "plaist" => "plaît" etc.

Comment: Je vous suis redevable et ai plussoyé. Compte tenu du fait que leurs prononciations sont les mêmes, pourriez-vous détailler pourquoi pas "taît" ?

Comment: @LePressentiment: ce n'est pas une question de prononciation (l'accent circonflexe ne change rien à la prononciation de la lettre "i") mais d'étymologie.

Comment: @LePressentiment: L'accent circonflexe a été introduit artificiellement au 16è siècle pour remplacer un s disparu (par ex asne -asne, en anglais le s de *ass* est resté). "Plaire" et "taire" avait en ancien français un s (*plaisir* et *taisir*). Pourquoi à un moment y a-t-il eu un accent circonflexe sur "plaît" et pas sur "tait", je ne sais pas si on peu le dire. Mais la réforme de l'orthographe de 1990 a recommandé de ne plus mettre d'accent circonflexe sur "plait" pour s'aligner sur "tait".